# Execute more than one sqlite3_exec, doesn't create tables, why?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite

I have this code, who create a new database 'fazerbem.sqli', with 4 tables:

```
-(void)iniciarBancoDeDados{

    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fazerbem.sqli"]];
    NSLog(@"DB Path: %@", databasePath);

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO) {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK) {
            char *errMsg;


            const char *sql_clientes =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fazerbem_clientes (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nome VARCHAR)";

            const char *sql_produtos = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fazerbem_produtos (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, codigo VARCHAR)";


            const char *sql_fornecedores = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fazerbem_fornecedores (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , telefone VARCHAR)";

            const char *sql_marcas = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fazerbem_marcas (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, marca VARCHAR)";



            if (sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, sql_clientes, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK && sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, sql_produtos, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK && sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, sql_fornecedores, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK && sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, sql_marcas, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {

                NSLog(@"A cricao do banco de dados falhou");

            } else {

                NSLog(@"O banco foi criado com sucesso");

            }



            sqlite3_close(myDatabase);
        } else {

            NSLog(@"Abertura e cricao do banco falharam");

        }
    }

}
```

Through an insert command, I could insert new values ​​in `fazerbem_clientes` table, but when I tried to insert values ​​in table `fazerbem_produto` values ​​were not being recorded, After a while, I used a command to return the error message on the insert and saw that he was claiming that `fazerbem_produtos` table did not exist.

Well back in the code above, how can I solve this problem? For this time the four tables are created successfully?

Comment: What is logged when you run the code above. Which NSLog is executed?

Comment: The way to solve your problem is to, first and foremost, check ALL return codes, log ALL "non-normal" return codes, and, when a "non-normal" return code occurs, also log the result of calling `sqlite3_errmsg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect in the `if` statement. If the 1st call to `sqlite3_exec` returns `SQLITE_OK` (meaning that it worked), the others will not be called and you end up in the `else` statement.

Try it this way:

```
if (sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, sql_clientes, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) == SQLITE_OK &&
    sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, sql_produtos, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) == SQLITE_OK && 
    sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, sql_fornecedores, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) == SQLITE_OK && 
    sqlite3_exec(myDatabase, sql_marcas, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"O banco foi criado com sucesso");
} else {
    NSLog(@"A cricao do banco de dados falho");
}
```

This will show success if all 4 succeed.

Comment: Logging the value of `errMsg` in the case of failure might also indicate why things are going wrong

Comment: @RichTolley Logging errors is always a good idea but in this case there is no error. It was a simple logic problem that prevented all but the 1st call to `sqlite3_exec` from even being called.

Comment: This method solve me problem, but I need to rename the database to fazerbem.sqlis, but fazerbem.sqli compromised, I have one question for yours! How can I Delete all the database who my command is creating?

Comment: You should accept this answer to close this question. If you have further questions, post them as another question. You will get better responses that way.

Comment: -1 The above is NOT the right way to do it.  The return code should be individually checked after each `sqlite3_exec`, and, if not "good", it should be logged, along with the result of `sqlite3_errmsg`.

Comment: @HotLicks The answer explains why the original code was only executing 1 of the 4 queries. It is not meant to be a definitive answer on writing proper error handling. That wasn't the question and is out of scope for the answer.

Comment: I disagree.  Adding proper error checking is always the FIRST step in dealing with any SQLite problem.

Comment: @HotLicks Then post your own answer showing the OP your idea of a fully correct approach to SQLite error handling. My answer solved the question being asked.